# Counting unival subtrees

Tags: c, interview-questions

I have written some code to solve the following interview question. Please advise how it can be improved. Thanks in advance.

A unival tree (which stands for "universal value") is a tree where all nodes under it have the same value. Given the root to a binary tree, count the number of unival subtrees.
For example, the following tree has 5 unival subtrees:

```
    0
   / \
  1   0
     / \
    1   0
   / \
  1   1
```

Implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct stTree
{
    struct stTree * left;
    struct stTree * right;
    int value;
}

stTree;

stTree* createNode(int value)
{
    stTree *node = malloc(sizeof *node);
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    node->value = value;

    return node;
}

bool isTreeUniv(stTree *node)
{
    bool flag = true;

    if (!node)
        return false;

    if (node->right && node->right->value != node->value)
    {
        flag = false;
    }

    if (node->left && node->left->value != node->value)
    {
        flag = false;
    }

    return flag;
}

stTree* insertRight(stTree *currNode, int value)
{
    stTree *node = malloc(sizeof *node);

    currNode->right = node;
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    node->value = value;
    return node;
}

stTree* insertLeft(stTree *currNode, int value)
{
    stTree *node = malloc(sizeof *node);

    currNode->left = node;
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    node->value = value;
    return node;
}

unsigned int uTreeCount = 0;
void countUnivSubT(stTree *Node)
{
    if (isTreeUniv(Node))
        uTreeCount++;

    if (Node->left)
        countUnivSubT(Node->left);

    if (Node->right)
        countUnivSubT(Node->right);

}

int main(void)
{
    //build a tree
    stTree *rootNode = createNode(0);
    insertLeft(rootNode, 1);
    insertRight(rootNode, 0);

    insertLeft(rootNode->right, 1);
    insertRight(rootNode->right, 0);

    insertLeft(rootNode->right->left, 1);
    insertRight(rootNode->right->left, 1);

    countUnivSubT(rootNode);
    printf("total universal subree: %u\n", uTreeCount);

}
```

Comment: All the nodes under it (or just the direct children have the same number)? Your `isTreeUniv()` only checks direct children not all nodes.

Comment: I assumed that it checks direct children only, thanks for the catch. I will branch the code with this consideration.

Comment: hey folks, follow up question is posted here with the suggested considerations: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/252634/counting-unival-subtrees-follow-up. Thank you all for the review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Code-formatting

1. Putting the tag-type two lines down instead of on the same line as the closing brace is curious.

#### Managing trees

2. I wonder why you don't use `createNode()` in `insertRight()` and `insertLeft()`.
3. If you change to building the trees from the leaves down to the root instead the other way around, you only need a single `createNode()` accepting a value and two (possibly `NULL`) descendants.
4. Assuming that resource-aquisition always succeeds is quite brave.
5. Consider adding a way to free a tree, for best effect using constant space, even though using it just before tearing down the whole process is unconscionably wasteful.

```
stTree* createNode(int value, stTree* left, stTree* right) {
    stTree* r = malloc(sizeof *r);
    if (!r) abort();
    r->value = value;
    r->left = left;
    r->right = right;
    return r;
}

static stTree* findBottomLeft(stTree* node) {
    while (node->left)
        node = node->left;
    return node;
}
void freeTree(stTree* node) {
    if (!node) return;
    stTree* bottomLeft = findBottomLeft(node);
    while (node) {
        if (node->right) {
            bottomLeft->left = node->right;
            bottomLeft = findBottomLeft(bottomLeft);
        }
        stTree* old = node;
        node = node->left;
        free(old);
    }
}
```

#### The main part

6. If you don't need to modify something, don't require the right. Use `const`.
7. `isTreeUniv()` is just **broken**. It only checks the direct descendents, while it should recurse into them.
8. Consequently, `countUnivSubT()` is also wrong. Still, fixing `isTreeUniv()` would result in a \$O(n^2)\$ algorithm, when it should be \$O(n)\$. The idea is to get all the info you need at once.
9. Avoid globals. Using `uTreeCount` makes the code non-reentrant, and breaks locality of reasoning.

```
static bool countUnivSubTimpl(const stTree* node, const stTree* parent, size_t* count) {
    if (!node) return true;
    bool r = countUnivSubTimpl(node->left, node, count)
        & countUnivSubTimpl(node->right, node, count);
    *count += r;
    return r & node->value == parent->value;
}
size_t countUnivSubT(const stTree* node) {
    size_t r = 0;
    countUnivSubTimpl(node, node, &r);
    return r;
}

int main() {
    stTree* root =
        createNode(0,
            createNode(1, NULL, NULL),
            createNode(0,
                createNode(1,
                    createNode(1, NULL, NULL),
                    createNode(1, NULL, NULL),
                ),
                createNode(0, NULL, NULL)));

    size_t uTreeCount = countUnivSubT(root);
    printf("total universal subree: %u\n", uTreeCount);
}
```

Comment: I didn't spot `isTreeUniv()` failing to recurse (yet criticised its inefficiency believing it did).  Even a reviewer often sees just what they expect to see, not what's actually written!

Comment: should I post my updated version of code in new thread or just leave it since I found an answer. Not being familiar with codereview

Comment: Post a new review-request referencing this one if you want a review. Alternatively if you don't particularly want it reviewed, post an answer detailing what you changed, what advice you discarded, and your rationale. Try to give credit where due. You could also just decide that it's enough though.

Answer (score 3):

The one red flag is `uTreeCount`. This should not be a global, and in fact it is easy to rephrase your `countUnivSubT` to be fully re-entrant: have it return an integer, and do addition within the body, something like

```
unsigned countUnivSubT(stTree *Node)
{
    unsigned int uTreeCount = isTreeUniv(Node);

    if (Node->left)
        uTreeCount += countUnivSubT(Node->left);

    if (Node->right)
        uTreeCout += countUnivSubT(Node->right);

    return uTreeCount;
}
```

That said, you have an inner null check, so this can actually reduce to

```
unsigned countUnivSubT(stTree *Node)
{
    if (!Node) return 0;
 
    return isTreeUniv(Node)
        + countUnivSubT(Node->left)
        + countUnivSubT(Node->right);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**`const`**

Consider `const` with functions that do not alter the tree:

```
//  bool isTreeUniv(stTree *node)
bool isTreeUniv(const stTree *node)

//void countUnivSubT(stTree *Node)
void countUnivSubT(const stTree *Node)
```

This improves clarity of what code does and allows for select optimizations.

**Loop opportunity vs recursion**

Rather than a global and two recursive calls, perhaps loop on one side and recurse on the other:

```
unsigned countUnivSubT(const stTree *Node) {
  unsigned count = 0;
  while (Node) {
    count += isTreeUniv(Node);
    if (Node->left) {
      count += countUnivSubT(Node->left);
    } 
    Node = Node->right;
  }
  return count;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm is inefficient.

For each node, we examine all nodes in its subtree to determine whether they are all equal.  We should look to visit each node just once, and extract as much as we need in that single visit.  So, as we go, report back up whether the current node is a unival tree, as well as the count of unival trees at or below it.  We don't need to visit the children again, just use the retrieved information.  Like this:

```
static size_t countUnivSubT_impl(const stTree *node, bool *isUnival, int *value)
{
    if (!node) {
        return 0;
    }
    *value = node->value;

    /* initial values chosen to work if one/both children are null */
    int lval = node->value, rval = node->value;
    bool lunival = true, runival = true;

    size_t count_left = countUnivSubT_impl(node->left, &lunival, &lval);
    size_t count_right = countUnivSubT_impl(node->right, &runival, &rval);
    return count_left + count_right
        +  (*isUnival = /* N.B. assignment */
            lunival && lval == node->value &&
            runival && rval == node->value);
}

size_t countUnivSubT(const stTree *node)
{
    bool isUnival;
    int value;
    return countUnivSubT_impl(node, &isUnival, &value);
}
```

And use it in `main()`:

```
printf("There are %zu universal subtrees\n",
       countUnivSubT(rootNode));
```

(I corrected the spelling there, too).

Comment: You know there is no rule forcing the operand of `+` to be fully evaluated from left to right?

Comment: Oh, good catch - I did originally have separate statements, and mistakenly combined them overlooking the side-effects.  I've fixed that now!