# Counting unival subtrees - Follow Up

Tags: c, interview-questions, tree

This code is a revised version of the implementation which asked for an advice on improvement. Original post here: [Counting unival subtrees](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/252232/counting-unival-subtrees)
Credits to: [Deduplicator], [Reinderien], [Toby Speight], [chux].

The revised version was applied following changes:

1. Merge `insertRight(), insertLeft()` function into `createNode` function
2. free resources after use
3. used `const` if referenced memory address value is not altered.
4. fix `isTreeUniv()` into recursive version
5. get rid of globals

Revised code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct stTree
{
    struct stTree *left;
    struct stTree *right;
    int value;
} stTree;

stTree* createNode(int value, stTree *leftNode, stTree *rightNode)
{
    stTree *node = malloc(sizeof *node);
    if (!node) abort();

    node->left = leftNode;
    node->right = rightNode;
    node->value = value;

    return node;
}

bool isUnivSubTimpl(const stTree *node, const stTree *parent, size_t *count)
{
    if (!node) return 1;    //node without child count as unival subT

    bool r = isUnivSubTimpl(node->left, node, count) &isUnivSubTimpl(node->right, node, count);
    *count += r;

    return (r &node->value == parent->value);
}

size_t countUnivSubT(const stTree *node)
{
    size_t count = 0;
    isUnivSubTimpl(node, node, &count);
    return count;
}

static stTree* findBottomLeft(stTree *node)
{
    while (node->left)
        node = node->left;
    return node;
}

bool freeTree(stTree *node)
{
    if (!node) return true;
    stTree *bottomLeft = findBottomLeft(node);

    while (node)
    {
        if (node->right)
        {
            bottomLeft->left = node->right;
            bottomLeft = findBottomLeft(bottomLeft);
        }

        stTree *old = node;
        node = node->left;
        free(old);
    }
        return true;
}

int main(void)
{
    //build a tree
    stTree *rootNode =
        createNode(0,
            createNode(1, NULL, NULL),
            createNode(0,
                createNode(1,
                    createNode(1, NULL, NULL),
                    createNode(1, NULL, NULL)
               ),
                createNode(0, NULL, NULL)));

    printf("total universal subree: %u\n", countUnivSubT(rootNode));
    if (freeTree(rootNode))
        printf("memory released\n");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Good job - it's nice to see improvements from the reviews you've received.

I would recommend using logical `&&` rather than bitwise `&` in the computation `r &node->value == parent->value`.  Results should be the same, but programmers expect to see logical operators with boolean values.

The computation of `r` cannot use `&&` as is, because the right-hand side does need to be evaluated for its side-effects, even when the left-hand side is false.  I'd consider rewriting as separate expressions, so a future maintainer doesn't "correct" the `&` to `&&`:

```
bool l_un = isUnivSubTimpl(node->left, node, count);  /* updates *count */
bool r_un = isUnivSubTimpl(node->right, node, count); /* updates *count */
bool r = l_un && r_un;
```

Identifiers beginning with `is` are reserved for Standard Library extension, so I'd advise changing the name `isUnivSubTimpl`, particularly as it has external linkage.

It isn't clear to me why `freeTree()` returns a `bool`, as it only ever returns `true`.

Building the tree could be simplified a little with

```
stTree *createLeafNode(int value)
{
    return createNode(value, NULL, NULL);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I didn't know that standard library function naming convention.